# how to open a file, process the file, use the orginal file name and add "Clean" to the file name, save the processed file using the new name

Tags: python

What I want to do:

- Open a file and read it
- Create a new file name by using the original name of the file and adding “Clean” to the name so I know it has been processed and is now has a different name.
- Process the file
- Save the file using the new name  I created.

I have researched online to find what is wrong with my script. There are many posts on changing the name of a file but have not found one that uses the original file name, adds to the name and then saves the processed file with the new name.

**This is the file script:**

```
import os
import sys
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize

#walk through the files in the directory

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(cwd):

    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as filein:            
            fileinA = filein.read() 

#create the new file name
 
            name = "Clean " + filein.name
            print ("New Name to use for Renaming : " ,name)        
        print ( )
        print("File read in")
        print ( )
        print ("fileinA", fileinA)

 #change file contents to lower case

        print ( )
        print ("Lower Case")
        print ( )
        fileinB=fileinA.lower()
         print("fileinB", fileinB)
        print( )

#rename the file using the name created            
        os.rename("fileinB","name")
```

**This is the output:**

```
New Name to use for Renaming :  Clean 2022 Q3 IOU ErnCls FirstEnerg.txt
File read in
fileinA 

Good afternoon, and thank you for joining NorthWestern Corporation's Financial Results Webcast for the Quarter Ending September 30, 2022. My name is Travis Meyer. I'm the Director of Corporate Finance and Investor Relations Officer 

Lower Case
fileinB 
good afternoon, and thank you for joining northwestern corporation's financial results webcast for the quarter ending september 30, 2022. my is travis meyer. i'm the director of corporate finance name and investor relations officer 

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "F:/Python/Scripts RJS/Cleanup File for Processing/File Rename.py", line 63, in <module>
    os.rename("fileinB","name")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'fileinB' -> 'name'2022
```

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around `fileinB` and `name`. That makes them literals instead of using the variable values.

Comment: `fileinB` is not the filename, it's the contents converted to lowercase. The original filename is `filename`, the name of the cleaned file is `name`.

Comment: You're never writing the converted contents to the new filename. Why are you renaming anything?

Comment: You should be writing `fileinB` to `name`, not renaming it.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and ask **one** question. If there are a series of steps involved in completing the task, identify specifically where the problem is, [look for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) existing solutions **for that part**, and if all else fails, create a [mre].

Comment: "There are many posts on changing the name of a file but have not found one that uses the original file name, adds to the name and then saves the processed file with the new name." Really? Perhaps that is because it is really two problems: 1) figure out the new file name; 2) rename it. Since you have already researched how to rename it, clearly the problem is in determining the new name. So - **did you try to [check](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)** what is wrong with that part of the code? For example, by looking at the `os.rename("fileinB","name")` code?

Comment: (Hint: what is the name that you want to use for the new file - the actual string `"name"`, or the contents of the variable `name`? Similarly for the file that you want to rename. When you look at the existing examples of `os.rename` that you found in your search, how exactly is it called? Or, put another way: do you understand why the code `a = "test"; print("a")` will print `a`, and will not print `test`?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
os.rename("fileinB","name")
```

to:

```
with open(name, "w") as fileout:
    fileout.write(fileinB)
```

Comment: We've had this talk many times. The problem is clearly caused by a typo, or at least a simple logical error; and the question meanders and describes a multi-step focus. The question should be closed for multiple reasons (the typo and for needing more focus) and should not be answered.

Comment: thanks Barmar, that resolved my problem.  Cheers, BobS

Answer (score -1):

I would use glob to recursively search for files in a folder:

```
import os
import glob

# recursively go through files in `path_to_folder`:
for path in glob.glob(f"{path_to_folder}/**/*"):
    with open(path) as f:
        content = f.read()
    # split filename and dirname
    dirname, filename = os.path.dirname(path), os.path.basename(path)
    # construct new path
    new_path = os.path.join(dirname, f"clean_{filename}")
    # make content lowercase and save it
    with open(new_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(content.lower())
    # remove old file
    os.remove(path)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to relate to the question being asked at all, not that it should be answered in the first place. The problem identified isn't with listing files to rename, but with the actual renaming process - no issue with the `os.walk` approach (which is also entirely valid in general) was identified by OP. Please read [answer] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; answers should answer a properly asked question, not contribute general advice. Where there is no clear, *single* problem identified by OP or where the immediate reason for the error is a typo, do not answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel but I did the renaming as you can see. Just that - on the way - I solved it my way.